# Google Script: Clear content of cells with specific background (to slow)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, background, cell

I am new to Google Script and i got stuck.

The code below works perfectly, but it takes more than 10 min to loop through all named ranges.
It clears the content of cells, but not the one with green backgrounds.

```
function deletNoGreenCells() { 
var namedRange = ['HaM','BeM','LoM']
for (var k=0; k<namedRange.length; ++k) {
  var  range=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(namedRange[k])

for( var i = 1; i < range.getNumRows()+1; ++i){
 for(var j = 1; j<range.getNumColumns()+1;++j){
  if (range.getCell(i, j).getBackground()!= "#93c47d") {
range.getCell(i, j).clearContent()
 }}}}}
```

How can i get this faster?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Thank You Matthew for the link to call `getBackgrounds`, wich leeds me to this solution:

```
function deletNoGreenCells() { 
  var namedRange = ['HaM','BeM','LoM']
  for (var k = 0; k < namedRange.length; ++k) {
    var range =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(namedRange[k])
    var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
    for(var i = 0; i < range.getNumRows(); ++i) {
      for(var j = 0; j<range.getNumColumns(); ++j) {
        if (backgrounds[i][j] != "#93c47d") {
          range.getCell(i+1, j+1).clearContent()
        }    
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now it runs only 5 seconds. Thanks!

Comment: Great. You might get some more minor speed improvements by caching the values of things that aren't going to change -- `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`, `range.getNumRows()` and `range.getNumColumns()` into variables so you don't need to calculate them each time round their respective loops.

Comment: Thanks. Again a little bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but if you're just clearing the data from the non-green cells you might be able to do this:

1. Call `getData` on the range to get an array containing all the values
2. Call `getBackgrounds` on the range to get the corresponding array of background colours
3. Use the backgrounds array to update the data array, blanking out the elements you want to clear
4. Call `setData` on the range, passing back the modified array

It seems likely that reading and writing the data in big blocks like this will be quicker.